# How to design xml schema for digital circuits?

Tags: data-structures, logic, circuits

how can i design XML Schema for logical and digital circuits?

i cant find any help or manual for this work

for example i have a digital circuits with AND OR NOR ,... gates

now i want design xml and schema for that

thanks for help

soryy for bad english

Comment: why xml and not yaml, or sth else?

Comment: @NikosM. i am beginner and dont know yaml or ...

Comment: ok see my answer in xml as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example.

Assume the following circuit in symbolic notation:

Cir = ((A OR B) AND (C OR D)) OR (NOT(D) AND F), where OR , AND, NOT etc can be realized with serial/parallel connections etc..

XML scheme proposition:

```
<circuit>
    <gate-or>
        <element>
            <gate-and>
                <element>
                    <gate-or>
                        <element>A</element>
                        <element>B</element>
                    </gate-or>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <gate-or>
                        <element>C</element>
                        <element>D</element>
                    </gate-or>
                </element>
            </gate-and>
        </element>
        <element>
            <gate-and>
                <element>
                    <gate-not>D</gate-not>
                </element>
                <element>F</element>
            </gate-and>
        </element>
    </gate-or>
</circuit>
```

This is an example xml-scheme where the root element is circuit and can have gates or elements as children and each gate (eg gate-or or gate-and) can have elements as children etc..

Of course this is very verbose , a yaml or json representation scheme would be lighter

Comment: are there any pdf or learn reference for this subject?

Comment: [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) being eXtensible, can represent structured data, now the way one can use XML to represent and describe data is another matter, there can be other xml representations which describe the same circuit being more or less verbose, examples: http://www.w3.org/XML/, [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML), [MusicXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicXML) nd so on